# Storage Spaces 2012 R2 - can you 'lie' about SSD/HDD tiers?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

As far as I'm aware in Windows Server 2012 R2 you can configure Storage Spaces to have two tiers and it'll migrate data between them automatically. These tiers are called 'SSD' and 'HDD' and are meant to utilise those disk types.

My question is can you 'lie' to it about these and assign a disk pool of 15krpm HDD's to the 'SSD' tier and 7.2krpm HDD's to the 'HDD' tier - or does it somehow check this? I can't test this in our labs right now as the hardware hasn't arrived just yet sorry.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK you can run storage spaces even from within a HyperV virtual guest so I imagine yes.

Use the [Set-PhysicalDisk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848651.aspx) commandlet to set the media type which appears as nothing more than a label (and not an actual physical property):

```
Set-PhysicalDisk -UniqueId <String> –MediaType SSD
Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName <String> –MediaType HDD
```

And simply add all disks labeled as SSD to one tier and all disks labeled as HDD to your other tier.

```
New-StorageTier –FriendlyName SSDTier –MediaType SSD
New-StorageTier –FriendlyName HDDTier –MediaType HDD
```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2013/08/28/step-by-step-for-storage-spaces-tiering-in-windows-server-2012-r2.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this, I *suspected* that there were no checks but I wasn't certain, thank you very much.